# Inheriting default constructor fails in gcc and works in clang, which one's got the bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, g++, clang++

Take this simple example.

```c++
struct Base {
    // Base::Base() defined by the compiler
};

struct Derived: Base { 
    using Base::Base; // Should inherit Base::Base()

    Derived(int value):
        m_value(value)
    {}

private:
    int m_value; // If Base::Base() is invoked, it's default constructed
};

Derived t;
```

<strike>As far as I understand by reading [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#Inheriting_constructors), `Derived` should inherit the default `Base::Base()` constructor and the code above should happily compile.</strike>

**Edit**: my bad, the page I linked to tells exactly the opposite story. So it seems clang's got a regression.

However, all versions of gcc I've tried fail at it, complaining that `Derived` has no default constructor, whilst clang does it just fine, but **only since version 3.9.0**; g++-7 **segfaults**, even <sup>**1**</sup>.

You can see it by yourselves on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/3zz0bQ).

So, who's at fault here? Clang for allowing it, or gcc (bar the segfault) for not allowing it?

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Although it seems to do so only on godbolt, I cannot reproduce the segfault locally.

Comment: @Barry: Good work, my disciple. (Beat me to it by seconds)

Comment: the cppreference page you've linked says "All candidate inherited constructors *that aren't the default constructor*" etc.

Comment: You are of course right, @n.m., my bad. For some reasons I've missed that part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the compiler segfault is always a compiler bug. You should report that.

Second, default constructors are never inherited. From N3242 (the wording in N3797 is similar), [class.inhctor]:

> For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors **other than a constructor having no parameters** or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter, a constructor is implicitly declared with the same constructor characteristics unless there is a user-declared constructor with the same signature in the class where the using-declaration appears.

The default constructor of `Base` isn't inherited into `Derived`, so `Derived t` should be ill-formed since there's no valid constructor taking zero arguments.

---

In C++17, this is still ill-formed, though the wording is different. Still [class.inhctor], from N4618:

> When a constructor for type B is invoked to initialize an object of a different type D (that is, when the constructor was inherited (7.3.3)), initialization proceeds as if a defaulted default constructor were used to initialize the D object and each base class subobject from which the constructor was inherited, except that
>   the B subobject is initialized by the invocation of the inherited constructor.

To invoke `Base::Base()`, we'd have to start with `Derived::Derived()`. But there's no `Derived::Derived()`.

Comment: Thanks! So it seems clang's got a regression. I'm already on my way to submit a bug report for the segfault, but it only happens on godbolt. I should submit a bug for clang too, I guess.